# Is Spring MVC is performance issue in web application which is having more number of hits

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I don't know much about spring MVC but this question is assumption based on old MVC frameworks. Why i am thinking is see multiple requests are handled by single instance i.e. controllers (spring beans are singleton by default). So in this case is this a performance issue if the number of users of that web site is very huge.

Answer (score 3):

I do not quite understand what exactly you are asking for.

> spring beans are singleton by default

Yes, they are. This makes completely sense: Once the container is bootstrapped, you have all instances needed for answering requests. The fact, that they are instantiated once for the complete lifecycle and that there is only one instance helps lowering the impact of creating new instances.

Think of the system under load:

If they weren't singletons, every request a new instance of your controllers would be created. This takes (little) time, but it takes time at all. Then after the request is answered, the instances weren't needed anymore. A new request would create a new instance. So you litter your JVM with tons of "one-time-objects", which have to be garbage collected at some point in time. This leads to GC pauses. Which is unwanted behaviour. So, to improve throughput and responsetime, it makes sense to use `Singletons` (in the *Spring-sense*).

> So in this case is this a performance issue if the number of users of that web site is very huge.

No, on the contrary: this - as I said - improves performance.

Of course, if you fear the [Slashdot Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect) it would be smart to use a serverlayout with several redundant instances and a loadbalancer in front. But that is a topic for another thread.

Answer (score 0):

The fact the one instance or 10000 instances are used doesn't have any impact on performance.

What matters is the number of threads working in parallel. Whether these threads all use a single instance or each have their own instance of a controller doesn't change anything.

Comment: »The fact the one instance or 10000 instances are used doesn't have any impact on performance.« I doubt that. As I've written, the effect would be a secondary, indirect one: more objects litter your JVM, so the GC has to spend more time on cleaning up the mess. On the other hand: yes, with a bunch of big servers and enough worker threads, you wouldn't notice, but the effect would be there.

Comment: Let's take Struts2 vs. Spring MVC. Struts 2 instantiates a controller per request, and stores the request parameters in the controller. Spring MVC reuses the same controller always, but creates a command object (and many other objects, BTW) per request to hold the request parameters. So you'll always have a bunch of objects created by request. That's not what makes something significantly faster or slower. The JVM is very smart and fast at creating lots of short-lived objects and garbage-collecting them. What matters is access to shared resources, proper database queries, etc.

Comment: D'accord. The chances are higher, that the DB is your bottleneck or other things besides the mass of controller objects. But the question was, if `Singletons` are performant. And the answer is yes.

Comment: I don't disagree with that. What I disagree with is that non-singleton controllers are automatically less performant than singleton ones. The OP seemed to think that requests, since they are handled by a single controller, are queues to be handled one by one, in sequence. That's obviously not the case. A single instance is handling multiple requests in parallel. Each request being handled in one thread.

Comment: I want to add one more here, Struts 2 with spring integration, so that time also struts 2 spring plugin tool will create multiple action instances for each request. So what is if that action is injected with services. so this time each action will get new instance of service in action instance?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple requests are handled by single contrlloer instance is NOT thread-safe! Developers have to add sync process for some cases, this would be performance bottleneck! If request per controller instance, controller is thread safe, sync is not required for most cases. as for creating many controller instances, this won't cause heavy performance issue, and besides, modern computer's memory is very big enough.

PS: as I supplied in my comments:

This is not a true or false choise, request-per-controller and singleton controller are 2 strategies. It's hard to say which is better or worse. I just said the thread-safe is an important concerned point of the 2 strategies.

Comment: And yet, the most used Java web framework, uses singleton controllers. Go figure.

Comment: @JBNizet NO! most modern jave web framework do NOT use singleton controller!! Strut2 is an good example. it updated from strut1 which is singleton controller fromwork! obviously, requet-per-controller is main-stream of java web framework! you go figure!

Comment: Nobody uses Struts2. And I wouldn't qualify it as modern. A lot of people used Struts1, and there was no thread-safety issue. The most used framework nowadays is Spring MVC, which uses singleton controllers and services, and there is no thread-safety issue. Saying that singleton controllers cause thread-safety issues is a nonsense. It does if you don't understand what you're doing. And that's also true if controllers are not singletons.

Comment: This is not a true or false choise, request-per-controller and singleton controller are 2 strategies. It's hard to say which is better or worse.  I just said the thread-safe is an important concerned point of the 2 strategies. BTW, don't say nobody use struts2...a lot of peaple use struts1, this is irresponsible. this topic is closed. I won't talk about it any more.

Comment: I wouldn't have downvoted if you had told that in your answer. You didn't. You said: "Multiple requests are handled by single contrlloer instance is NOT thread-safe". That is plain incorrect.

Comment: OMG, it's a normal express, didn't you see I said in the second sentence:evelopers have to add sync process for SOME CASES! did I said ALWAYS? Whatever~

Comment: I do not quite understand: When multiple requests are handled by a single controller (which is as the TO stated a `Singleton`) this setup is not thread-safe. E.g. using class-global variables will bring you in hells kitchen. So @Laurence Geng is right when he says, they are not thread-safe. But that was not the question. It was about performance.

Comment: @ThomasJunk *using class-global variables will bring you in hells kitchen.* Yes. You should not do that. There is absolutely no reason to do that. Just like there is no reason to use static variables in frameworks using prototype controllers (which would also cause thread-safety issues). As I said, whatever the design choice the framework makes (both choices have their pros and cons, and are valid choices), if you know what you're doing, you won't have thread-safety issues. If you don't, you will.

Comment: @JBNizet but that is not, what Laurence Geng said: They aren't threadsafe. But nothing hinders you from circumventing this and write thread safe code.

Comment: They are thread-safe if you make them thread-safe. They aren't if you make them non-thread-safe. It's not as if the framework provided you a non-thread-safe starting point that you had to fix. Singleton like prototype controllers aren't inherently thread-safe or thread-unsafe. It all depends on how you code them. If you follow the rules and know what you're doing there's no problem with any of the two design choices. If you don't, there are problems with the two design choices.

Comment: As long as the controller as a singleton is stateless nothing bad happens. Spring MVC enforces that stateless design. One must be really out of touch with the framework to make it stateful.

Comment: @JBNizet Lets put it this way: prototype is not shared, hence no thread-issues. Singleton is shared: handle with care :]